# Problemas em configurar o LuaRocks

Tags: lua

Bem pessoal, eu venho tentando instalar o LuaRocks faz algumas horas, porém não obtive sucesso. Então eu instalei o WSl e depois um terminal Ubuntu no Windows, quando eu fui instalar o LuaRocks deu certo, porém há alguns erros na hora de dar o comando de configurar:

"Configuring LuaRocks version 3.9.1...

Lua version detected: 5.3
Lua interpreter found: /usr/bin/lua5.3
lua.h found: /usr/include/lua5.3/lua.h
Could not find 'unzip'.
Make sure it is installed and available in your PATH."

Então, alguem poderia me ajudar? :)

Answer (score -1):

acabei de resolver o problema. Bastou apenas um: **sudo apt-get install unzip**

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).